# Python: how to change values of two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
worker_1 = {
"name": "Peter",
"age": 46,
"salary": 24098,
"city": "Washington"
}

worker_2 = {
"name": "Adam",
"age": 52,
"salary": 19894,
"city": "Colorado"
}
```

How can I change the values of these two workers so that the worker_1 gets the values of worker_2 and worker_2 gets the values of worker_1?

Thanks

Comment: You want both to be updated with others values or you want to switch the dicts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```py
worker_1, worker_2 = worker_2, worker_1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp_worker = worker_1
worker_1 = worker_2
worker_2 = temp_worker
```

I would use a temporary variable because I like making sure there is no possibility of data loss or conflict.